# The state does not reappear if I select another country

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

The state field should be a hidden if I select country Mauritius, which works. The problem is that after choosing Mauritius, if I choose another country, the state field does not reappear.

```
<input id="state" name="state" type="text" placeholder="Amsterdam"
       style="visibility:visible" onfocus="con()">
<label for="country" id="country">Country</label>
            <select name="country">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
                                    your country</select>

function con() {
    var z=document.forms["task2"]["country"].value;
    var z11 = document.getElementById("male");
    var z12 = document.getElementById("state");

    if(z=="MU")
    {
        document.getElementById('state').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        z11.focus();
        return false;
    } else if(z!="MU") {
    z12.focus();
    document.getElementById('state').style.visibility='visible';
    z12.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the javascript in the question, not in the comments

Comment: use 'ctrl + k' to add code

Comment: ok, done, added the html code and javascript.. help me plz

Comment: is that the full code? because country is undefined when i run your code

Comment: you might want to try `.blur()` before doing another focus

Comment: code updated :)
i tried all possible events, not working!

Comment: This doesn't even fall under a jQuery question because no jQuery is used. If jQuery used, use visibility:hidden; and then use .toggle()

Comment: `con` should be done on `onchange` of country it seems. You cannot `focus` on a hidden/invisible element i guess.

Comment: @sabithpocker yeah, OP hide the only element that triggers the function that hide/show. If pure JS is not mandatory OP should consider using jQuery, might be easier to understand the mechanism here.

Comment: @user3036342 that's not the problem here

Comment: @TecHunter Whatever dude, he complains jquery isn't working when he's not even remotely using it. So don't care what the actual problem is, OP is an idiot

Comment: @user3036342 I don't see any mention of jQuery (besides the wrong tag). it's plain JS with the use of a wrong event.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Maslow/pXMdL/

It needs to be onchange and there were other errors, like not listening to the select change. which is probably where your listener should have been in general. Also your sample didn't include the html for the form.

"your country" was outside of any valid elements (inside `<select>` but not inside an `<option></option>` tag.

Comment: it is working on the link but not working for ma form. checked the code several time, its same to same! the state field do not even disappear! y? :(

Comment: show more of your code for more detailed answers. otherwise it'd be a guess